# Google autocomplete js disappeared, now has display: none

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

Today my Google auto-complete input field disappeared, and it seems like something adds 'display: none' to the style in the element (not CSS).

I have found some other solutions that override the '.pac-container' CSS class with high Z-index and it seems to make it appear again, but then it doesn't show any search results. Anyone know why this happens and what a good solution is?

Is this perhaps standard if Google api key is invalid or something simple like that?

Here is my script import:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try changing the API version to release (v=3) or frozen?

Comment: @geocodezip this seems to work for me, do you have any reference about the version specification or why it would stop working without it?

Comment: Without the v=3, you are using the "experimental version".  That periodically breaks (and/or changes in major ways that break other code).  [Versioning description in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I think you should go for an actual answer here.

Comment: We managed to solve it before reading here, but thank you @geocodezip for explaining why it broke, if you want to post an answer I will gladly mark it as answer, for now I posted my own answer to make sure it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! The solution was to set a specific API version, so we changed this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31&libraries=places&key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
```

Thanks to comment from "geocodezip" I now understand why:

> Without the v=3, you are using the "experimental version". That periodically breaks (and/or changes in major ways that break other code). [Versioning description in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)